# forcing a bit in a wire

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

From testbench, I have to corrupt a bus in design.
I am using a random variable to select a bit location (`bit_sel`)

```
bit_sel = $urandom_range(0,MAX_LENGTH-1);
```

Bus is somewhere deep inside the RTL with a width of `MAXLENGTH`.

```
wire [MAX_LENGTH-1:0] BUS_TO_BE_FORCED;
```

In TB, I am using following line to corrupt the bus:

```
force TOP.DUT.....BUS_TO_BE_FORCED[bit_sel] = ~TOP.DUT.....BUS_TO_BE_FORCED[bit_sel];
```

But, I am getting compilation error. What is the best way to do this? I want to flip only one bit.

Answer (score 3):

You could instead flip the bits using a XOR mask:

```
wire [MAX_LENGTH-1:0] corrupt_bits = 1 << $urandom_range(0,MAX_LENGTH-1);

force BUS_TO_BE_FORCED = corrupt_bits ^ BUS_TO_BE_FORCED;
```

Comment: This is not working for me. force statement is a part of some procedural block right.

Answer (score 2):

The LHS must be a *constant* bit-select of a vector net (among other things). So,

`force TOP.DUT.....BUS_TO_BE_FORCED[0]`

is Ok, but

`force TOP.DUT.....BUS_TO_BE_FORCED[bit_sel]`

isn't. You could try a big case statement, because the selectors don't have to be constant:

```
case(bit_sel)
 0: force TOP.DUT.....BUS_TO_BE_FORCED[0] = ...
 ...etc
```

Comment: I thought of same but my MAX_LENGTH is in 100's and i have handful of buses like that. I tried generate statement. But generate doesn't work inside a procedural block.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** the initial answer contained my guesses, along with completely wrong information. I should not have answered this question in the first place, therefore I had to write test-benches and confirm the following statements to compensate for the mess.

1) Bit select must be a constant (at compile time). Even the following code (perfectly reasonable in my opinion) won't pass elaboration:

```
integer bit_sel;
initial begin
    bit_sel = 0;
    force BUS_TO_BE_FORCED[bit_sel] = 1'b1;
end
```

2) If used inside "initial" block, the following statement is fine:

```
force BUS_TO_BE_FORCED[SOME_PARAM] = ~BUS_TO_BE_FORCED[some_index];
```

- SOME_PARAM is a parameter
- some_index may be a variable or a net
- SOME_PARAM = some_index

However, the same statement inside "always" block causes the simulation to hang. This issue may be resolved by adding delay:

```
#1 force BUS_TO_BE_FORCED[SOME_PARAM] = ~BUS_TO_BE_FORCED[some_index];
```

3) The answer by Eric is a very elegant way around language's limitations, but it is also subject to limitations described in section 2 above - you'll have to add delay if you want to use it in "always" block.

Comment: The value used by the force statement is only evaluated once, but continuously driven. Versus a `$deposit` which drops the value once on to the Wire/Reg. The `force` is used in an initial or always block and follows the standard rules for procedural evaluation (think regs, or assignment in a non-parallel language).

Comment: I see that I made very incorrect statement in my answer. Correcting.

Comment: No Problem, we are all here to learn. NB: I also use variable bit selects in synthesised code (of constant width), this is safe. This just represents muxing logic.

Comment: Vasiliy: `always` is `initial forever`. In other words, it just loops continuously. Unless you put in a timing control (something like your `#1`, or `@(posedge clk)`, or whatever) then the sim will hang, whatever statements you have inside the always. Your hang isn't related to the `force`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and resorted to using another vector of equal width to the signal to be corrupted. I also encapsulated this in an interface so that I could bind it to any part of the DUT as necessary. Refer to the code below:

```
import uvm_pkg::*;
`include "uvm_macros.svh"

interface sync_signal_fault_injector #(
  parameter int SIGNAL_WIDTH = 1
) (
  input                     clk,
  input                     reset,
  input [SIGNAL_WIDTH-1:0]  signals
);

  bit [SIGNAL_WIDTH-1:0] toggle_bits = '0;

  class sync_signal_fault_injector_c extends uvm_object implements fivip_pkg::Injectable;
    function new(string name="fault_injector");
      super.new(name);
    endfunction

    virtual function int unsigned get_size();
      return SIGNAL_WIDTH;
    endfunction

    virtual task inject(ref int unsigned indices[], input int unsigned delay);
      repeat (delay) @(posedge clk);

      foreach (indices[id]) begin
        int unsigned bit_index = indices[id];
        if (bit_index >= get_size()) begin
          `uvm_fatal("BOUNDS",
            $sformatf("Tried to access bit %0d but signal bus is only of size %0d", id, get_size())
          )
        end
        // Prepare toggle bits
        toggle_bits[bit_index] = 1;
      end

      force signals = signals ^ toggle_bits;
      @(posedge clk);
      release signals;
      // Reset toggle bits
      toggle_bits = '0;
    endtask

  endclass

  sync_signal_fault_injector_c fault_injector = new;
endinterface
```