# How to force a single bit in an array of bits in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog, test-bench

I'm now trying to force a bit in an array of bits. The position of bit to be "forced" depends on the variable i while others bits keeps 0.
for example, if I have the array bit `[2:0] A`
when `i=0`, I want `A` to be `3'b001` when `i=1`, `A` should be `3'b010` when `i=2`, `A` should be `3'b100`
but I have to use force statement since I'm writing testbench to test path of signals.
Does anyone know how I can do that?

update 1: @Serge I have to use the force statement it was declared like this: bit [31:0] A I tried this: force A[31:0] = 32'd0; for (int i=0;i<=31;i++) begin force A[i]=1; end Obviously it doesn't work. Actually I was testing different scearios to see if the path of the signal is properly done or not

update2: I have now generated a script to force the signal one by one
However, I'm not sure whether I encounter a bug or not
when this statement is executed
a[31:0] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,`TOP_TB.clk_1T,0};
a[1] keeps to be 0. Instead, the 1T clk appear at a[0]. Does anyone know what's happening?

update3: Thanks for your help!!I have actually thought that the 0s are interpreted in 32 bits, but I don't really know why the 1T clk appears at bit 0 instead of bit 1 (I'm using questasim). Btw, I have solved this by generating a script and copy and paste the content inside a text file generated by the script.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful for you to add what you have tried already, so we can see what exactly you are having a problem with. (For example, do you want to force the value `3'b001` when `i` is 0, or do you want to just force bit `[0]` of A? In either case, what's the problem?) **Please edit your question to supply this information, please don't add it in a comment.**

Comment: What does it mean "forced" in your interpretation? Verilog has an ability to `force` a net in test bench so that it cannot be changed. This is not synthesizable. Did you mean `force` statement or just assigning a value to a bit of an 'array'? What is this array: `net`, `var`? How was it declared? you need to provide your coding attempt in order for us to understand your intention better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bit-indexing in verilog to do what you want.  It's like indexing into an array in C.  For example:

```
array_a[i] <= new_value;
```

In the code above, if i is 0, it will assign new_value to bit 0 and keep the rest unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

From the Language Reference Manual (IEEE Std 1800-2017), section 10.6.2 ("The force and release procedural statements"):

> The left-hand side of the assignment can be a reference to a singular variable, a net, a constant bit-select of a vector net, a constant part-select of a vector net, or a concatenation of these. It shall not be a bit-select or a part-select of a variable or of a net with a user-defined nettype.

It appears that it is not possible to do directly what you want.

My best bet for doing more or less what you want to do (I just forced the single bit and left the other ones evolving as normal), keeping in mind that the LHS of the force assignment should be constant, is something like this:

```
module dut (
    input   logic   [31:0]  a,
    input   logic   [31:0]  b,
    output  logic   [31:0]  z
);

    always_comb z = a & b;

endmodule: dut

module tb;
    logic [31:0] a;
    logic [31:0] b;
    logic [31:0] z;

    dut dut (.*);

    logic clk = 0;
    initial forever
        #(5ns) clk = !clk;

    logic [5:0] sel;
    initial forever begin
        case (sel)
            6'd0: force z[0] = clk;
            6'd1: force z[1] = clk;
            6'd2: force z[2] = clk;
            6'd3: force z[3] = clk;
            6'd4: force z[4] = clk;
            6'd5: force z[5] = clk;
            6'd6: force z[6] = clk;
            6'd7: force z[7] = clk;
            6'd8: force z[8] = clk;
            6'd9: force z[9] = clk;
            6'd10: force z[10] = clk;
            6'd11: force z[11] = clk;
            6'd12: force z[12] = clk;
            6'd13: force z[13] = clk;
            6'd14: force z[14] = clk;
            6'd15: force z[15] = clk;
            6'd16: force z[16] = clk;
            6'd17: force z[17] = clk;
            6'd18: force z[18] = clk;
            6'd19: force z[19] = clk;
            6'd20: force z[20] = clk;
            6'd21: force z[21] = clk;
            6'd22: force z[22] = clk;
            6'd23: force z[23] = clk;
            6'd24: force z[24] = clk;
            6'd25: force z[25] = clk;
            6'd26: force z[26] = clk;
            6'd27: force z[27] = clk;
            6'd28: force z[28] = clk;
            6'd29: force z[29] = clk;
            6'd30: force z[30] = clk;
            6'd31: force z[31] = clk;
        endcase
        @(clk or sel);
        release z[0];
        release z[1];
        release z[2];
        release z[3];
        release z[4];
        release z[5];
        release z[6];
        release z[7];
        release z[8];
        release z[9];
        release z[10];
        release z[11];
        release z[12];
        release z[13];
        release z[14];
        release z[15];
        release z[16];
        release z[17];
        release z[18];
        release z[19];
        release z[20];
        release z[21];
        release z[22];
        release z[23];
        release z[24];
        release z[25];
        release z[26];
        release z[27];
        release z[28];
        release z[29];
        release z[30];
        release z[31];
    end

    initial begin
        a = 32'h0055aaffaa55ff00;
        b = 32'habcdef0123456789;
        sel = 6'd0;
        #(98ns);
        sel = 6'd6;
    end
endmodule: tb
```

This works on my version of ModelSim (INTEL FPGA STARTER EDITION 10.6c).

As for why your code:

```
a[31:0] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,`TOP_TB.clk_1T,0};
```

does not work, my best guess is that every "0" is interpreted as an **integer** 0, i.e. 32'd0. You then effectively have something on the line:

```
a[31:0] = {960'd0, `TOP_TB.clk_1T, 32'd0};
```

an the RHS gets truncated to fit into just 32 bits. The truncation of course implies anything left of "32'd0" is thrown away, but your compiler should really raise a warning about this. Something like:

```
a[31:0] = {30'b0,`TOP_TB.clk_1T,1'b0};
```

works for me. You can of course plug that construct in the "case" I used in my example too.

Answer (score -1):

Systemverilog does not let you force a bitslice of a vector, so you'll have to force the whole net. A good strategy here is to force the net to be:
`force A = A ^ my_force_vector;`
And set my_force_vector to the bits you'd like to force.

See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50845703/6262513

Comment: I have seen the code inside, actually the RHS of the force statement is not constant. I want to force the specific signal bit to be a clock signal, so I don't think this method would work since "my_force_vector" is only assigned once, but not continuously

Comment: You can create a more elaborate force for this:
`force A = (A & ~my_force_vector) | (my_force_vector & clock_vector);`

Use `my_force_vector` to drive the net to 0. Clock vector will probably look like:
`clock_vector = {myclk1, myclk2...};`

Comment: Working example on EDA playground: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3RaC